# How to send messages to different windows in electron?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

I'm writing my first electron app, so please be lenient :)

When the user presses a button on the main Window, there should open a new window which shows some json string.
This event gets cought by ipcMain:

```
ipcMain.on("JSON:ShowPage", function(e, item) {
    createJSONWindow(item);
})
```

This is the function where I create the new window:

```
function createJSONWindow(item) {
    let jsonWin = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 600,
        height: 800,
        center: true,
        resizable: true,
        webPreferences:{
            nodeIntegration: true,
            show: false
        }
    });
    jsonWin.loadFile("jsonView.html");

    ipcMain.on('JSON_PAGE:Ready', function(event, arg) {
        jsonWin.webContents.send('JSON:Display', item);
    })

    jsonWin.once('ready-to-show',()=>{
        jsonWin.show()
    });

    jsonWin.on('closed',()=>{
        jsonWin = null;
    });
}
```

Now to my question, when I have multiple `JSONWindow`s open, every single one of them gets the `JSON:Display` Message and updates it's content. Shouldn't they work independently from each other? The `jsonWin` is always a new `BrowserWindow`, isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
ipcMain.on('JSON_PAGE:Ready', function(event, arg) {
      jsonWin.webContents.send('JSON:Display', item);
})
```

Every time you create a new window, you are having `ipcMain` subscribe to the same message. This means that when `ipcMain` gets the `'JSON_PAGE:Ready'` message, it calls every single callback it has registered and sends a message to every single window.

---

The simplest solution in this case is to use the event that's passed to the `ipcMain` handler to send the message to the renderer that sent it to main. Second, subscribe a single time outside of `createJSONWindow`:

```
ipcMain.on('JSON_PAGE:Ready', function(event, arg) {
      e.sender.send('JSON:Display', item);
});
function createJSONWindow() { ... }
```

However, is `'JSON:Display'` simply sent when the page has loaded? If so, you can subscribe the window's webContents to the [`did-finish-load`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-finish-load) event which fires when the page has loaded.

```
jsonWin.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
    jsonWin.webContents.send(...);
});
```