# When closing a BrowserWindow in electron, event listeners continue to reference the BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, electron

My title probably doesn't properly capture my question, but I could not find a succinct way to capture the issue.

The issue is like this:

I have a BrowserWindow that is triggered by an IPC event. When the BroswerWindow opens, it sends a message back to the main process to signal that it has completed loading, and then the main process sends it some data with which to perform a specific task. Upon completion of the task, the user closes the window and execution of a different process begins.

This all works fine, except that it the application receives that event to open the BrowserWindow again, the event handler that sends data to the new window either throws an error indicating that it cannot send data to the windows because the process has been destroyed OR reopens the window, but with all of the old data from the first time that the windows was opened, when what I need is a fresh instance of the window. I know that I could simply use javascript to tear down and regenerate the original HTML, but I feel like there must be a better way. Here is the code below:

**main.js**

```
const electron = require ("electron");
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
function openNewWindow() {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ autoHideMenuBar: true });
    win.loadURL(__dirname + '\\new_window.html');
    win.webContents.openDevTools()
    win.on('closed', function () {
       win = null;
    })
    return win
};

let mainWindow;

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
   if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
     app.quit ();
   }
});

app.on('ready', function () {
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
                    title: app.getName() + " - v" + app.getVersion(),
                    autoHideMenuBar: true
   });

   mainWindow.loadURL ('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

    //This event handler opens the new window when it receives the open-new-window event
    ipcMain.on('open-new-window', (event,arg) => {
        console.log('Arg = ' + arg);
        let newWindow = openNewWindow();
        //This event handler sends data to the new window when the new window indicates that it is done loading
        ipcMain.on('done-loading',(event2,arg2) => {
            console.log(arg2);
            newWindow.webContents.send('test',arg);
        });
    });

   // Close the application when the window is closed
   mainWindow.on ('closed', function() {
     mainWindow = null;
   });
});
```

[image: This is the error that I get when triggering the open-new-window event after closing the new window:]

The reference to line 52 in the error message is to this line:

```
newWindow.webContents.send('test',arg);
```

The new window opens, but no data is sent to it.

Comment: instead of using `ipcMain 'done-loading'` event try with `BrowserWindow ready-to-show` Refer [this](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#using-ready-to-show-event)

Comment: @Eldar thanks, but doesn't seem to be working. I need it to load all of the javascript before sending the data, not just render the html. Plus, it's not clear to me that this would solve the essential issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58986728/3479456) question.

Every `open-new-window` event causes you to resubscribe `ipcMain` to the `done-loading` event for the new window, but it still maintains the subscription/closure to the old window.

You do not want to do `ipcMain.on("done-loading", ...)` inside of the the new window handler.

You want to do it outside of the window handler and instead send a response back to the same webcontents by using the event argument:

```
ipcMain.on('open-new-window', (event, arg) => {
    openNewWindow();
});

ipcMain.on('done-loading', (event, arg) => {
    event.sender.send('test', arg);
});
```

---

However, there is a `did-finish-load` event that does what you seem to want to do:

```
function openNewWindow() {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ autoHideMenuBar: true });
    win.loadURL(__dirname + '\\new_window.html');
    win.webContents.once("did-finish-load", () => {
        win.webContents.send("test", ...);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yea, it definitely seemed like that's what was happening...The thing is that I need to be able to access the arg variable from the open-new-window event. I guess that I could send an event back to the window that sends the open-new-window event and tell it to send the arg after done-loading is trigerred. Or I could assign the arg to a global varialbe in main.js. Thanks! I'll try this out and accept the answer if it works!

Comment: you can get the created-window and map its `id` to the arg. I don't know what sends the `done-loading` event, but it could send the window ID as an arg, so you can look up the arg you want to send to the window. that's one idea